# how to identify relationship/mapping between the two list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created two list.

```
list1= [a,b,c,a,d]
list2=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to find relationship between this two list based on index position  i.e

In list1 `a` is repeated 2 times index `0,3` .in list2  index `0,3`  values are `1 ,4`  the relation is a one  to many is a:`{1,4}`

next `b`  not repeated  in list `1` and it index is `1` and list2 index `1` value is `2` ,the relation is one to one `b:{2}`

my expected output will be `{a:{1,4},b:{2},c:{3},d:{5}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = defaultdict(set)
for value1, value2, in zip(list1, list2):
    result[value1].add(value2)

print(dict(result))
```

outputs

```
 {'a': {1, 4}, 'b': {2}, 'c': {3}, 'd': {5}}
```

Comment: Good answer. Can be simplified further with `zip()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of dictionary and list comprehension to do this:

`{x: [list2[i] for i, j in enumerate(list1) if j == x] for x in list1}`

output:

`{'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [5]}`

Comment: That's a pythonic way of  doing it.

Comment: Although this is `O(n^2)` whereas the other answers are `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ret = {}
for idx, _a in enumerate(a):
    value = ret.get(_a, ret.setdefault(_a, []))
    value.append(b[idx])
```

And ret will be the output

Answer (score 0):

Option is to zip the two lists:

```
L = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Result:

```
 [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 4), ('d', 5)]
```

Use it to create a dictionary with sets as values:

```
D ={}
for key in L:
    if key[0] not in D:
        D[key[0]] = {key[1]}
    else:
        D[key[0]].add(key[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it this way in real code, but this approach is mildly entertaining and perhaps educational.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

xs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

d = {
    x : set(y for _, y in group)
    for x, group in groupby(sorted(zip(xs, ys)), key = itemgetter(0))
}

print(d) # {'a': {1, 4}, 'b': {2}, 'c': {3}, 'd': {5}}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not from pure python, as this question tagged with `pandas` I tried this way.

Option-1

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'l1':list1,'l2':list2})
res1=df.groupby('l1').apply(lambda x:x.l2.values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

Option-2

```
print df.groupby('l1')['l2'].unique().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 4], 'c': [3], 'b': [2], 'd': [5]}
```